# GuzzleHttp request sends garbled characters

Tags: php, utf-8, guzzle6, guzzle

I use GuzzleHTTP 6.0 to get the data from the API server. For some reason the request which the API server receives are not UTF-8 endoded the characters `ü,ö,ä,ß` are garbled characters.

My default System and Database is `UTF-8` encoded.

I set `debug` to `true` in the `RequestOptions` this is the output:

`User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.2.1 curl/7.47.0 PHP/7.0.22-0ubunut0.16.04.1 
Content-type: text/xml;charset="UTF-8" 
Accept: text/xml" Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 2175 * upload completely sent off: 2175 out of 2175 bytes
<HTTP/1.1 200 OK <Server:Apache:Coyote/1.1 <Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 <Transfer-Encoding: chunked <Date: Thu, 23 Nov 2017 9:34:12 GMT <* Connection #5 to host  www.abcdef.com left intact`

I have set explicitily the headers contents to UTF-8;

```
    $headers = array(
        'Content-type' => 'text/xml;charset="utf-8"',
        'Accept' => 'text/xml',
        'Content-length' => strlen($requestBody),
    );
```

I also tried to test using `mb_detect_encoding()` method

```
mb_detect_encoding($requestBody,'UTF-8',true); // returns UTF-8
```

Any further ideas how do i debug this issue..??

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Length` must contain number of bytes, not number of characters. That could the reason if you use `mbstring.func_overload`. Try to omit manual set of this header, Guzzle will set it automatically in the correct way for you then.